# sending data to URL from FB - ZAPIER

Tags: javascript, url, send, zapier

I'm trying to send data out of zapier on FB lead fetch.

is there anyway to do it?

or i must use external php file first?

i need to get name, email and send it to CRM (which is not listed in zapier) my CRM can use URL or XML input. No normal JS API.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Zapier has webhooks](https://zapier.com/zapbook/webhook/) that let you send data out. Your CRM is then responsible for processing that data (converting it to the right format, etc). You could also add your CRM as a Zapier app that can accept data from your trigger source and perform necessary API calls, updates, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found

`fetch('http://clients.frontask.co.il/WebToLead.aspx&type=get&FirstName='+input.name+'&Email='+input.email+'&Phone='+input.phone+'&lead_from='+input.lead+'&SystemID=UpdateExistingDetails=[1]', { method: 'GET' }).then(function(res) {return res.text();}).then(function(body) {var output = {id: 1234, rawHTML: body};callback(null, output);}).catch(callback);`

do the job, but i faced another problem.
because of the system restrictions i cannot use url, i need to send XML file. 
Any change I can do it?
thanks